# Matrix problem involving an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Please could you help me with the below question. There are three parts, and all of my working is displayed! Thank you in advance, kind stranger.

**For an integer n, real numbers a,b,c and an nxn matrix A for which: $ A^3+aA^2+bA+cI_n =0_n $**

**a) Assume that c does not equal 0, show A is invertible**

Invertible => an nxn matrix B exists such that AB=In=BA.
I found B to be: $ B=\frac{-1}{c}(A^2+aA+bI_n) $

**b) Asume c=0 and b does not equal 0. Show A is invertible if and only if $ A^2+aA+bI_n=0 $**

Assuming A is invertible: $$ A^{-1}(A^3+aA^2+bA)=A^{-1}0_N => A^2+aA+bI_n=0_n$$

Assuming $ A^2+aA+bI_n=0 $:

*SOLVED - thank you Michael Hoppe and copper.hat*

**c) Write down two 3x3 matrices B which satisfy: $B^3-2B^2-6B+6I_3=0_n$**
*I can see that a=-2, b=-6 and c=6 and from part a), we know that B must be invertible. From here, I do to not know how to continue.*

Comment: You may want to read about the Cayley Hamilton Theorem for Matrices. Its about the fact that a matrix satisfies its own Characteristic equation. Those are the equations you wrote down in each part of the question

Comment: @imranfat Had a look at Wiki for this and I can see what you're saying, I just don't see how this would help me answer my questions?

Comment: for (c), one way is to use [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) follows form the same considerations as a); $A(A+aI) = -b I$, so $A(-{1 \over b}(A+aI)) = I$.

For c), note that $f(x) = x^3-2x^2-6x+6$ has three distinct real roots ($f(-3)<0, f(2)>0, f(1)<0, f(4)>0$), call them $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3$.

Let $B_1 = \lambda_1 I = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  \lambda_1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B_2 = \lambda_2 I= \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Since each $\lambda_k$ satisfies $f(\lambda_k) = 0$, we see that $f(B_i) = 0$ too.

Comment: Haven't covered anything like that in lectures/classes for c), any other (simpler!) suggestions?? (Thank you btw)

Comment: What part is causing difficulty? Do you know that $f$ has three roots?

Comment: We haven't covered diag.

Comment: I have removed the diag notation.

Comment: Oh, we just say like λ1I3 for that kind-of thing.

I've emailed my lecturer now asking for help. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (b): from $A^2+aA+bI_n=0$ you know that $A(A+aI_n)=-bI_n$.